# Put Data from dataSet in a chart rdlc report

Tags: c#, charts, dataset, reporting, rdlc

i need your help !

I'm actually on a project, i got csv files with data, the first column is the date and others columns is data from different sensor. I actually put theses data in a DataTable and after that on a DataSet.xsd

I got an RDLC report and i want to display chart with the data from my DataSet. I tried many times but this does not work, i cant see my data on my chart !

Hoping that you can help me !

Have a great Day, and sorry if my english is not perfect.

Comment: Please paste your code and elaborate on what you have tried exactly and what were the results.What excactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

i put my data in my DataSet like this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DTTrends.Rows)
        {
            //On créer une nouvelle ligne
            dr = Ds_Impression.Courbes1.NewRow();
            //On rempli la ligne
            dr["Date"] = row[0].ToString();
            dr["Capteur1"] = row[1].ToString();
            dr["Capteur2"] = row[2].ToString();
            dr["Capteur3"] = row[3].ToString();
            dr["Capteur4"] = row[4].ToString();
            dr["Capteur5"] = row[5].ToString();
            dr["Capteur6"] = row[6].ToString();
            dr["Capteur7"] = row[7].ToString();
            dr["Capteur8"] = row[8].ToString();

            Ds_Impression.Courbes1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

I verify, the data in my DataSet is the same as my datatable and i'm trying to display my values according to the date in a chart in my RDLC report : https://ibb.co/LnPC1YV

Iwant the Date on X axis and Value from "Capteur2" on Y Axis